# java.io.FileNotFoundException when java program start from cmd of runnable jar

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception, getresource

i have a card game project that works fine untill i use eclipse to open it up.

if i try to export it to a jar file or launch it from cmd, i keep having java.io.FileNotFoundException whenever i try to acces to folders or files.

For example i have a AudioManagert class that plays the resource giving his path as string.

this is working if i launch the program from eclipse, it doesn't from cmd.

Another example is when i try to load an image to create a new ImageIcon

**new** ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/src/controller/resource/account.jpg"));

this would work on eclipse, not from cmd

how can i fix this problem? is there something to do with the use uf the path as a string?

here my AudioManager class method play()

```
public void play(String filename) {

        try {
            
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

here my call from the program too it


                                AudioManager.getInstance().play("./src/resource/sposta.wav");

this works on eclipse, not on cmd
```

[i add the image of where my audio and image resource are stored inside my project....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfub7.png)

Comment: You don't want to be using paths that are anything to do with your dev environment. Store your files somewhere always accessible (e.g. off `user.home`) and give the absolute path. You don't know from [where it will be run](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/91-find-the-current-directory-in-java)

Comment: the file i m handling are located inside the project folder, in a folder that i called resource inside myproject\src. i tought that would be standard for all because contained in the project folder. what if i have to acces to images stored inside my JAR to get profile images, game images, ecc?

Comment: Any resource files should be located in `src/main/resources`, so next to `src/main/java`. Those will be automatically included in the jar, and can be accessed using `Class.getResource` like you showed.

Comment: The case I'm discussing here is playing audio files. If they are always in the same place then they are resources, and would be included in your compilation unit as @Jorn has said. I was referring to cases where you might want the user to choose a file to play

Comment: @Jorn  That is only true for Maven projects

Comment: @Stewart It's true for Gradle too, and those two together should cover at least 95% of all projects.

Comment: You're both right. I think what @Stewart could be getting at is that making `src/main/resources` suddenly in the Eclipse project is not necessarily going to see the resources correctly packaged. But I don't know - I don't use it

Comment: Your source files start as follows? `package controller;`?

Comment: yes, im using mvc pattern and i put main.java inside the controller package. Should i create a Main package for main.java?

Comment: That's alright. Are those wav files in a *subdirectory* of *directory* 'controller'? (Difficult to see from the gui)

Comment: there is a directory, thath is the path to a file:
/src/controller/resource/song.wav

Comment: if i call AudioManager.getInstance().play("./src/controller/resource/song.wav"); it works in eclipse, it still wont work from JAR

Comment: Not the best arrangement, but what you need in your current situation is `InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/controller/resource/pesca.wav"));` See [here](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)